# php: find variable characters in an array

Tags: php, variables

Got a varibale that holds phone number and the number have it country prefix before it and the phone number is dynamic and can be any phone number from any country.
So, I need to get the country of the phone number by matching certain characters (i.e the country prefix preceding the phone number) in the variable against the record in the DB (country prefix would be fetched into an array) holding all country prefix.

Sample:

```
$phoneVar = '4477809098888';  // uk - 44
$phoneVar = '15068094490';  // usa - 1
$phoneVar = '353669767954';  // ireland - 352
$phoneVar = '2348020098787';  // nigeria - 234
```

If the $phoneVar is assigned any phone number value, need to be able to get the country prefix out of it.

Something like this:

```
echo getCountryPrefix($phoneVar, $countries_prefix_array);
```

This would have been easy to achieve using substr

```
// $countryPrefix = substr($phoneVar, 0, 3);
```

But countries do not have the same prefix length.

Would be pleased to get help with this.

Comment: I think you will need some DB with prefixes, because you can't make any script on lenght, because each country have their prefixes and their phone number lengths.

Comment: Also be aware, that the order of the match is relevant. I would first try to compare the longer prefixes (1684 -> American Samoa) first before checking the short ones (1 -> USA).

Comment: i would suggest having the prefix be a separate input field, it would be easier then getting the correct prefix out of the variable when the prefix is  of a variable length, as is the phone number itself.

Comment: you need a table in the data base to  store the prefixes of each country, then use the table data according to requirement..

Comment: @Nasir, I have a table with countries and their respective country prefix. Just cant figure out out to match a specific number against the array of country prefix.

Comment: @Patrick Evans, I actually wished I could get the number and country prefix separately passed but the project does not allow that. The number comes together with the prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is a perfect example for a state machine !

simplest way:

```
$prefixes = array('44' => 'UK', '1' => 'USA', '352' => 'IRELAND', '234' => 'NIGERIA');
preg_match('/^('.implode('|',array_keys($prefixes)).')/', $phoneVar, $matches);
echo $prefixes[$matches[0]];
```

Comment: The code is meant to take care of any number from any country and not just (uk, usa, ireland, nigeria) the ones used as example in the question. Would appreciate a broader solution. Tanx

Comment: what about simply filling the prefixes array from a database ? Of course i didn't mean to limit it to this 4.

Comment: So sorry I mixed your code up with some other one. And I just went through it correctly alongside the DB record of prefix and it works great... Tanx a million!

Comment: No problem ;) a precompiled state machine would do even faster (but this is hard to implement with a dynamic database).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work.

It's probably not accurate to your code, but I'm sure you can see the logic.

```
function findCountryCode($number, $country_codes) {
    $country_codes = usort($country_codes, 'lsort');

    foreach ($country_codes as $key => $val) {
        if (substr($number, 0, strlen($val)) == $val)
            return $key;
    }

    return false;   

}


function lsort($a,$b) {
    return strlen($b)-strlen($a);
}
```

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Possible workaround would be ordering the country codes by length. Not ideal, but then neither is the structure of the stored data.

Comment: even ordering by length wont help, if you had a number 15554567450 how do you know if its country code 15 or country code 1.

Comment: @PatrickEvans: that is not an error, phone numbering logic avoid that kind of error, sorting by length should be ok

Comment: @PatrickEvans: lets say you are in a non 1 or 15 prefix country if you dial the 15554567450 the operators will know to which country to redirect you... I'm guessing 1-555-4567450 is an us number therefore there will be no numbers starting with 5 after country code 15 like 15-5***** is not available.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this [schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes) useful.

The coding is straight-forward, if you maintain a map of prefix to country code.
Sort the prefixes, start at the back so 123 is tried before 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like following codes:

```
$phoneVar = '4477809098888';  // uk - 44

$county_list = array('uk' => 44, 'usa' => 1, 'ireland' => 352, 'nigeria' => 234);

foreach ($county_list as $key => $value)
{
    if (preg_match('/^'.$value.'/', $phoneVar))
    {
        echo "Country is: ".$key;
        echo "Country code: ".$value;
        break;
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Country is: uk
Country code: 44
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match() :

```
$phoneVar = "abcdef";
$pattern = '/^44/';
preg_match($pattern, $phoneVar, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r("UK : ".$matches);
```

This can mean lengthy code. But if its just 4 countries then this would serve your purpose.

Comment: The code is meant to take care of any number from any country and not just (uk, usa, ireland, nigeria) the ones used as example in the question. Would appreciate a broader solution. Tanx

Comment: okay.. you just need to loop it. @Bora has done just this. Two answers above mine. Im not editing since it would look like simply copying his answer..:)